Unable to Upload Files to S3 from Django on Amazon Lightsail, Despite Working Fine Locally with Same Credentials and Policy
I'm running into an issue where I can successfully upload files to my S3 bucket locally, but I encounter problems when trying to upload from my server. Here are the details:
Django Settings
Settings.py (relevant parts):
STATIC_URL = "https://my-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/static/"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = env("STATICFILES_STORAGE")

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = env("AWS_S3_REGION_NAME")
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = env("DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE")
MEDIA_URL = env("MEDIA_URL")

S3 Policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-cdn/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPutObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::id:user/my-cdn"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-cdn/*"
        }
    ]
}

Issue:

Local Environment: Uploading files to the S3 bucket works perfectly.
Amazon Lightsail Server: Uploads fail (No logs whatsoever), but the credentials and policy are the same.


If the uploads fail without any logs, you need to increase your log level. Are you using the django-storages library to implement this? If so, that typically won't fail without errors in my experience. You should try to verify somehow that those environment variables are actually set to the values you think they are on your LightSail instance.
